# Python dictionary with same key for parsing in a url so must be ordered

Tags: python, urllib2

I have a problem trying to create a dictionary, ordering it and joining it for parsing with urllib2.
This is my code:

```
values = {'STR':'1',
       'STR':'123',
       'STR':'3456',
       'BAT':'95'}
ary_ordered_names = []
ary_ordered_names.append('STR')
ary_ordered_names.append('STR')
ary_ordered_names.append('STR')
ary_ordered_names.append('BAT')
queryString  = "&".join( [ item+'='+urllib.pathname2url(values[item]) for item in ary_ordered_names ] )
print queryString
url = 'url'
full_url = url + '?' + queryString
print full_url
request = urllib2.Request(url, queryString)
response  = urllib2.urlopen(full_url)
html = response.read()
print html
```

So when I execute this script it works but only send last STR value, 3456, not the rest.
Could anyone help me with any trick for this python dictionary problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not just an ordering issue. Dictionary keys must be unique, so at execution `values` only ends up being `{'STR': '3456', 'BAT': '95'}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dictionaries have no ordering and keys must be unique. Instead, pass a list of `(key, value)` *tuples* to the [`urllib.urlencode()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) function if order is important:

```
from urllib import urlencode

params = [('STR', '1'), ('STR', '123'), ('STR', '3456'), ('BAT', '95')]
query_string = urlencode(params)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from urllib import urlencode
>>> params = [('STR', '1'), ('STR', '123'), ('STR', '3456'), ('BAT', '95')]
>>> urlencode(params)
'STR=1&STR=123&STR=3456&BAT=95'
```

You can also use a sequence for the values and pass in `True` for the `doseq` parameter:

```
params = [('STR', ['1', '123', '3456']), ('BAT', '95')]
query_string = urlencode(params, True)
```

This produces the same output:

```
>>> params = [('STR', ['1', '123', '3456']), ('BAT', '95')]
>>> urlencode(params, True)
'STR=1&STR=123&STR=3456&BAT=95'
```

If the order of `BAT` and `STR` relative to one another does not matter, you can still use a dictionary, but use a sequence for the `STR` values:

```
params = {'STR': ['1', '123', '3456'], 'BAT': '95'}
query_string = urlencode(params, True)
```

The `STR` values are then grouped in order, but the `BAT` parameter can end up after or before that group:

```
>>> params = {'STR': ['1', '123', '3456'], 'BAT': '95'}
>>> urlencode(params, True)
'BAT=95&STR=1&STR=123&STR=3456'
```

Comment: Really thanks for your answers.
Another question related is, Can I use urlencode or any other function for doing this?

    'BAT=95&STR=1,123,3456'

Comment: @RobHy: just use `str.join()` to join the values before passing it as *one* string to `urlencode()`; `params['STR'] = ','.join(['1', '123', '3456'])`.

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, the order in a python dict is not guaranteed.

One option is to use a list of `(key, value)` tuples.

Another is to use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects). [Edit: This would only work in the situation where there aren't any duplicate keys.]

Comment: An OrderedDict won't support multiple repeated keys either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, you are correct.  I didn't notice the overloading of keys originally.